# There was an error granting Firebase Service Agent access to your secret

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

I am facing an error while installing an Algolia extension into my firebase project.

Error-

[image]

When I click on the "Create secret" button, the error below is visible

[image]

Comment: Did you follow the recommendations explained in the `Description` in the first image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only admin can add Key. Check your project permission

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When installing the extension it will ask you to enable the secrets API, what this does is enables the Secrets Manager API from google cloud (what firebase is built on top of). You can manually check this is enabled with the below URL, and if its not - enable it.

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/secretmanager.googleapis.com/overview?project=YOUR_PROJECT_ID

As with all google cloud API's, when you enable them it takes a few minutes for the changes to propagate. Try again in ten minutes, and you will find your error is resolved, you're able to create the secret, and you can install the extension.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue might be related to your billing account. There could be an issue with your billing details, similar to an experience I had. It's worth double-checking to ensure everything is in order.